# Agudath Israel not in the Conference of Presidents

Tags: chutz-laaretz, tzibur-community, organizations, orthodox

Does anyone know why [Agudath Israel of America](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agudath_Israel_of_America) is [not a member](http://www.conferenceofpresidents.org/content.asp?id=55) of [the Conference of Presidents of Major American Jewish Organizations](http://www.conferenceofpresidents.org/content.asp?id=52)?

Comment: [probably](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agudath_Israel_of_America#Positions) because the [Rabbinical Assembly](http://www.rabbinicalassembly.org/) and the Union for [Reform Judaism](http://urj.org/index.cfm) is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since it includes Reform and Conservative organizations in its roster.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agudath_Israel_of_America#Positions

> In 1956 for example, the moetzes issued a written ruling forbidding
>   Orthodox rabbis to join with any Reform or Conservative rabbis in
>   rabbinical communal professional organizations that then united the
>   various branches of America's Jews, such as the Synagogue Council of
>   America.